# How to show validation error in my form instead of getting IntegrityError?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I am creating a portfolio app, in which there are two models:

```
class Portfoller(AbstractUser):
    career_options = [('Developer','Developer'), ('Artist', 'Artist'), ('Writer','Writer')]
    gender_options = [('Male', 'Male'), ('Female', 'Female'), ('Other', 'Other')]

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=gender_options, default='Male')
    birthdate = models.DateField('birthdate')
    country_of_birth = CountryField()
    career = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=career_options)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True)
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to=profile_picture_path, default='generic_user.png')
    biography = models.TextField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)

    def get_age(self):
        now = timezone.now()
        return now.year - self.birthdate.year - ((now.month, now.day) < (self.birthdate.month, self.birthdate.day))

class Project(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Portfoller, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    project_description = models.TextField(max_length=1024)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('project_name', 'user')
```

And now I am making a view to add a Project to a Portfoller:

```
class AddProject(View):
    def get(self, request, username):
        form = AddProjectForm()
        form.instance.user = get_object_or_404(Portfoller, username=username)
        return render(request, 'portfolio/add_project.html', {'form': form})
    
    def post(self, request, username):
        form = AddProjectForm(request.POST)
        form.instance.user = request.user
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('portfolio:profile', kwargs={'username': username}))
```

The problem is that when I get a project_name equals to an existent project project_name I want to get a form error in the form page, but instead, I'm getting a:

> IntegrityError at /users/admin/add-project/
> duplicate key value violates unique constraint "portfolio_project_project_name_user_id_4b215f4d_uniq"
> DETAIL:  Key (project_name, user_id)=(Farkle, 17) already exists.

How to solve it?

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

app_name = 'portfolio'

urlprojects = [
    path('', views.ProjectView.as_view(), name='project'),
    path('edit-project/', views.EditProject.as_view(), name='edit_project'),
    path('delete-project/', views.DeleteProject.as_view(), name='delete_project'),
]
urlusers = [
    path('', views.ProfileView.as_view(), name='profile'),
    path('edit-profile/', views.EditProfile.as_view(), name='edit_profile'),
    path('add-project/', views.AddProject.as_view(), name='add_project'),
    path('<str:project_name>/', include(urlprojects)),
]

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.HomeRedirect.as_view(), name='home-redirect'),
    path('home/', views.PortfollerList.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('users/<str:username>/', include(urlusers)),
    path('signup/', views.signup, name='signup'),
    path('signin/', views.signin, name='signin'),
    path('signout/', views.signout, name='signout'),
]
```

forms.py:

```
class AddProjectForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ['project_name', 'project_description']
```

add_project.html:

```
    <body>
        {% extends "portfolio/base.html" %}
        {% block content %}

        <h2>Add project:</h2>
        <form method="post">
          {% csrf_token %}
          {% for field in form %}
            <p>
              {{ field.label_tag }}<br>
              {{ field }}
              {% if field.help_text %}
                <small style="color: grey">{{ field.help_text }}</small>
              {% endif %}
              {% for error in field.errors %}
                <p style="color: red">{{ error }}</p>
              {% endfor %}
            </p>
          {% endfor %}
          <button type="submit">Add</button>
        </form>
      {% endblock %}
  
      {% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}
    </body>
```

Comment: The field `user` in model `Project` is mandatory, but it's not a part of your form, so where do you think the `ValidationError` should come from?

Comment: There is a way to show the ValidationError without allowing the user to change the user to which will be created the Project? I would like to allow only a logged user to create a new project in its own Profile (still not implemented), so I would not like to give an option to change the user to which the project will be created.

Comment: My point is the `ValidationError` can be raised only by having invalid data in the form. The user is not a part of the form, and something what is not there can't make it invalid and raise `ValidationError`. The data in form are valid and that is where the job for the form ends. The `IntegrityError` happens because you're not providing a value for the `user` column for the model. Not necessarily from the form as an input field, but it needs to be a part of the data and you can inject it in there from `request.user`, which contains the actually logged in user, which you want.

Comment: if you would like to raise `ValidationError`, what would be the expected error there? "sorry the form does not contain User field (because it can be spoofed) and the programmer didn't provide the value under the hood neither, so this form will never work"?

Answer (score 1):

`ValidationError` is raised when you are saving into DB, which hapepns when you call `form.save()`. Wrap that part into try-except and reraise `ValidationError` in such case:

```
def post(self, request, username):
    form = AddProjectForm(request.POST)
    form.instance.user = request.user
    if form.is_valid():
        try:
            form.save()
        except IntegrityError:
            raise ValidationError("something")

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('portfolio:profile', kwargs={'username': username}))
```

sidenote: you should also handle the situation when `is_valid()` returns `False`

Comment: Sorry, now I realize that when I was trying to solve my problem (before post this question), I mess up the code, and I didn't see that it was returning a different error than the one which I was trying to solve, the error for "IntegrityError at /users/admin/add-project/ null value in column "user_id" violates not-null constraint" is solved, and now we can go to my true error: "IntegrityError at /users/admin/add-project/
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "portfolio_project_project_name_user_id_4b215f4d_uniq"
DETAIL:  Key (project_name, user_id)=(Farkle, 17) already exists."

Comment: So what I would like to do is to show this Integrity error at my form, how can I do that without allowing the user to change the user to which the Project will be created?

Comment: It helped me, but we still don't get to the result that I would like, now when I try to create a project with a project_name equal to another project project_name in the same profile it returns me: ValidationError at /users/admin/add-project/
['something']
But what I would like to do is show the ValidationError at the form, to the user.